# Spring Integration tcp-outbound-channel-adapter that detects connection loss and auto-reconnects

Tags: spring-integration

I'm trying to do the exact opposite of what is being accomplished here:

[How do I create a tcp-inbound-gateway which detects connection loss and auto-reconnects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19188360/how-do-i-create-a-tcp-inbound-gateway-which-detects-connection-loss-and-auto-rec)

I have a set of collaborating client tcp adapters taken from the sample application. In general the application will be sending a high volume of client requests to a 3rd party over a shared connection, but there will be times when there are no requests coming through at all.

Because of this, there is a requirement from the 3rd party that says I should send them a ping message every 2 minutes. If the response to the ping isn't received in a predefined period of time(which could be shorter than the timeout for other calls, I should kill the connection and reconnect.

My first thought was to created a scheduled task that will send the ping every 2 minutes, but I'm not sure how I would kill the connection and re-establish it from inside the task. Another option, I was considering was to use the connection interceptor and time the request and response, but that doesn't seem right. I am brand new to SI, so any push in the right direction would be helpful.

Another I just had was autowiring the tcp-outbound-channel-adapter into the job and calling retryConnection()

```
<converter>
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.integration.samples.tcpclientserver.ByteArrayToStringConverter" />
</converter>

<!-- Given we are looking for performance, let's use
     the most performant wire protocol. -->

<beans:bean id="fastestWireFormatSerializer" class="org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.serializer.ByteArrayLengthHeaderSerializer">
    <beans:constructor-arg value="1" />
</beans:bean>

<!-- Client side -->

<gateway id="gw"
    service-interface="org.springframework.integration.samples.tcpclientserver.SimpleGateway"
    default-request-channel="input" />

<ip:tcp-connection-factory id="client"
    type="client"
    host="localhost"
    port="${availableServerSocket}"
    single-use="false"
    serializer="fastestWireFormatSerializer"
    deserializer="fastestWireFormatSerializer"
    so-timeout="10000" />

<publish-subscribe-channel id="input" />

<ip:tcp-outbound-channel-adapter id="outAdapter.client"
    order="2"
    channel="input"
    connection-factory="client" /> <!-- Collaborator -->

<!-- Also send a copy to the custom aggregator for correlation and
     so this message's replyChannel will be transferred to the
     aggregated message.
     The order ensures this gets to the aggregator first -->
<bridge input-channel="input" output-channel="toAggregator.client"
        order="1"/>

<!-- Asynch receive reply -->
<ip:tcp-inbound-channel-adapter id="inAdapter.client"
    channel="toAggregator.client"
    connection-factory="client" /> <!-- Collaborator -->

<!-- dataType attribute invokes the conversion service, if necessary -->
<channel id="toAggregator.client" datatype="java.lang.String" />

<aggregator input-channel="toAggregator.client"
    output-channel="toTransformer.client"
    correlation-strategy-expression="payload.substring(0,3)"
    release-strategy-expression="size() == 2" />

<transformer input-channel="toTransformer.client"
    expression="payload.get(1)"/> <!-- The response is always second -->
```

**Update**

I am using SI 3.0.7.RELEASE

The only exception I see in the log is:

22:02:38.956 ERROR [pool-1-thread-1][org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnection] Read exception localhost:4607:39129:464bd042-dd9c-4639-8d1d-cdda61dc988a SocketTimeoutException:Read timed out

This is when the so-timeout on the clientFactory is set to 10 seconds and I force the server to sleep for 15 seconds. Nothing is ever returned to the SimpleGateway call. It just sits there and waits forever.

Sample Code using the configuration listed above:

```
String input = "ping";
                String result = null;
                System.out.println("Sending message: " + input);
                try{
                    result = gateway.send(input);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println("There was an exception sending the message");
                }
                System.out.println("response: " + result);
```

Output:

Sending message: test
22:12:17.093 ERROR [pool-1-thread-1][org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnection] Read exception localhost:4607:39232:fe90d394-edc3-440a-ab68-34e7162db6ec SocketTimeoutException:Read timed out

The gateway call never returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a [new component in 4.2 called `Thread Barrier`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#barrier).

This allows you to wait for some (configurable) time until an async event occurs.

See [the barrier sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/barrier) for an example.

The ping reply would 'release' the waiting thread; in the case of the timeout you could use a request handler advice on the handler to catch the exception and take the action you need (you can get a list of open connections from the factory and close them by id).

BTW, we could probably rewrite that sample to use the barrier instead of an aggregator.
There's really no need to reopen the connection (unless you anticipate unsolicited responses on a new connection); it will be opened on the next send.

**EDIT**:

I need to see more of your log; I just tried it and got the following:

```
2015-09-28 09:05:53,995 [pool-2-thread-1] ERROR: org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnection - Read exception localhost:5678:51323:f3537a39-feb4-4237-9508-7e67c1b79654
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
...
2015-09-28 09:05:53,996 [pool-2-thread-1] TRACE: org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway - onMessage: localhost:5678:51323:f3537a39-feb4-4237-9508-7e67c1b79654([Payload=java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out][Headers={timestamp=1443445553996, id=0b3fae63-f431-c09c-ac4e-26ce4b012b6b, ip_connectionId=localhost:5678:51323:f3537a39-feb4-4237-9508-7e67c1b79654}])
2015-09-28 09:05:53,996 [main] DEBUG: org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway - second chance
2015-09-28 09:05:55,998 [main] ERROR: org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway - Tcp Gateway exception
org.springframework.integration.MessagingException: Exception while awaiting reply
...
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
...
```

However, it is broken in 4.2 (and for single-use sockets) so I have opened a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3837). But yours is not single-use so I would expect the same results as mine.

**EDIT 2**:

```
Skipping a socket timeout because we have a recent send localhost:4607:26489:926b1c1f-49cc-4f44-b20d-78f2e94e82d1
```

I should have mentioned this before.

Because the connection factory supports completely asynchronous messaging, we might have to wait for 2 timeouts before closing the socket and propagating the exception to the gateway thread.

The reasoning is thus (using your 10 second `so-timeout`):

1. Connection created at `t+0`; the read thread is started and is blocked in the socket (not interruptible).
2. Message sent at `t+9`.
3. Read times out at `t+10`.
4. It would be too early to use this timeout so we ignore it because there has been a send within the last 10 seconds.
5. Read times out again at `t+20`.
6. Exception propagated to caller.

On average, the gateway thread will get the timeout at `so-timeout * 1.5`, but it will be in the range `so-timeout` to `so-timeout * 2`.

**EDIT 3**:

I can't tell from the log why it's not being propagated in your case.

I just reverted the tcp-client-server sample on [this branch](https://github.com/garyrussell/spring-integration-samples/tree/propSoTimeoutTest/basic/tcp-client-server) to 3.0.7 and changed the test to force a timeout (after skipping one), and it all worked fine for me.

We need to figure out what is different about your case and mine.

You can see the changes I made to the sample in [the last commit on that branch](https://github.com/garyrussell/spring-integration-samples/commit/fb674397b4b90a3ca47f53b06d25c75c7d549e06).

If you can come up with a similar test case that reproduces the problem, I can help you debug it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The system I am integrating SI into is using Spring 3.2.5 so I am stuck using SI 3.0.7.

Comment: Maybe I can use some sort of callable method with a timeout to send the ping and close the connection if it times out.

We're supposed to maintain a single shared connection with the 3rd party server, but maybe this isn't necessary.

Comment: You can grab the source for the `BarrierMessageHandler` from 4.2 and port it back to 3.0.x. You just won't have namespace support - invoke it as a `<service-activator/>` to suspend and an inbound channel adapter to trigger. But, as you say, it might be easier to just roll your own.

Comment: I'll keep working on it and post the final solution. Thanks for the info.

Comment: So, I've been trying to read up as much as I can, and I think the easiest route is just to create a second gateway and make it an async gateway and put a timeout on the method. 

I'm facing 2 more issues. I set the so-timeout=5000 on the tcp-connection-factory and I make the server sleep for 30 seconds so the connection times out. On the client side, I see a read exception in the logs, but that does not cause the method to return an error. How can I catch this timeout error.

Comment: The second issue is, how can I manually reset the connection in the scheduled task. I thought it would be as easy as autowiring the tcp-outbound-channel-adapter into the scheduled task, but when I did so, but class that got wired in was and instance of EventDrivenConsumer  and not TcpSendingMessageHandler as I expected

Comment: 1. See [TCP Connection Events](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html#tcp-events).
2. You can close the connection (by id) by calling the connection factory's 'closeConnection` method.

Comment: I took a look at TCP Connection events. What I was hoping to do was propagate the connection loss as an exception up to the gateway call. Is it not possible to do this? 

Is there a simple way to know the id of the connection you are currently using?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were talking about an async timeout (no current outstanding request). What version of the framework are you using? Connection errors have been propagated to an in-use gateway request since 3.0... https://github.com/garyrussell/spring-integration/commit/0301f262e0fbef9775c1631ea16971029241a199 If you are still seeing a problem; please post a DEBUG log (client side) somewhere (probably too big for stack overflow; use a gist or pastebin etc).

Comment: I updated my solution with an example of what is happening. I have also found that I can get the behavior I want by adding 'default-reply-timeout' to the service gateway. Ideally, I would still like to find out why the connection timeout exception is not being propagated from the connection factory up to the service gateway.

Comment: It should be propagated since 3.0. I will take a look tomorrow when I'm back at my desk. If you can post a debug log someplace it might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks. I posted the full output at the end of the update above. There isn't much, just the SocketTimeoutException:Read timed out. There isn't a stacktrace printed.

Comment: Here is a more complete log. http://pastebin.com/6KZKEK46

I see that the first timeout is skipped, but when the second timeout occurs, it is not propagated to the gateway. The gateway call never returns. Considering the setup described above, if the method returned, we would see "There was an exception sending the message" in the logs.

Comment: Also, to get the SI updates committed for the jira ticket, do I need to rebuild SI myself? Or is there a nightly build? I'm not sure how that works.

Comment: I'll look at your log tomorrow - it's not clear why you might see different behavior. I'll also provide a test case that shows it working fine for me; perhaps you can provide a simple test case that exhibits your observed behavior. The [project page](http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/#quick-start) has information about how to get the nightly snapshots (maven, gradle). Select the 4.2.1 snapshot from the dropdown for the repo info, but plug in 3.0.8 instead. But, as I said, with your configuration you don't need the patch.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I appreciate all of the help. I created a git repo demonstrating the issue. https://github.com/mrj365/si-multiplex-timeout-test The readme explains the modifications made to duplicate the problem

Comment: Doh - sorry I guess I didn't read your question fully - my test was with the normal (sync) `tcp-client-server` sample. Of course, with a completely async application (such as the multiplex sample) there __is__ no thread waiting for a reply at the TCP level, and hence there's nothing to propagate it to within the adapter itself. We can, however, handle it via the aggregator. If you were using a recent release, you could add a `group-timeout` to the aggregator; with 3.0.x you have to configure a reaper - I'll push a commit to my clone of your app.

Comment: See [this commit](https://github.com/garyrussell/si-multiplex-timeout-test/commit/2cce58d1bc3981cf01b031658a7c0b4bdfddc60a) to your test case. 1. Add a 20s timeout to the gateway so null will be returned when no response at all. 2. Add a reaper to the aggregator's message store and timeout the group after approximately 10 seconds (see the [reaper docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#reaper) for more information. When a group times out, return a `MessageTimeoutException` to the gateway.

Comment: And [here's the 4.2.x version](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/pull/147).

Comment: Ahhhh, it all makes sense now! Thanks!